# How to configure the resource and crud operation programmatic according to the user permission on react-admin

Tags: resources, crud, admin-on-rest, react-admin

I was using react-admin, it's really quickly and productively. However, I want to implement some features like programmatic display resource and crud operation component according to the attributes of a logged user.

Something like this.

```
const App = () => (
    <Admin restClient={jsonServerRestClient('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com')}>
        <Resource name="users" list={UserList} haveListPermission={user.hasUsersListPermission}/>
        <Resource name="tags" havePermission={user.hasTagPermission} />
    </Admin>
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is documented here: https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Authorization.html

In a nutshell, the `Admin` component accepts a function as children (think render prop) which will be called with your permissions (from your `authProvider`). So assuming you are using `react-admin` (and not `admin-on-rest`) and your `authProvider` resolves with the current user when called with type `AUTH_GET_PERMISSIONS`:

```
const App = () => (
    <Admin authProvider={authProvider} dataProvider={jsonServerRestClient('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com')}>
        {user => (
            {user.hasUsersListPermission && <Resource name="users" list={UserList} />}
            {user.hasTagPermission && <Resource name="tags" />
        )}
    )}
    </Admin>
);
```